# Is there a way to compile a C++ file without the terminal?

Tags: c++

I am on a computer distributed by my school, and the command line cannot open. Every C++ tutorial I've looked at so far involves opening the terminal to launch the code. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Do you have a browser? You can compile online, e.g. with [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/).

Comment: hi, interesting, you could use a [web-based c++ compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler), or a [free AWS lightsail account](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/)

Comment: I do have a browser, I will try that quick. I can just use a .cpp file that I made in the atom code editor or something like that, right?

Comment: Learning how to effectively use the terminal is a skill that's very valuable, so don't give up on it. That being said, Visual Studio Community and XCode are both self-contained compiler suites so they don't require the terminal.

Comment: what's the OS this computer is? Can you install soft in it? If you can, you can install a c++ IDE to compile. :)

Comment: Tadman, I'll try your solution too. Thanks for all of the answers!!!

Comment: And, Elapsed Soul, it is a Windows 10 Education edition. Some things are restricted, though, so I don't now if I will be able to download it. I'll try, though! Thanks!

Comment: If you're really up against a wall you can also try booting off of a live USB drive into Ubuntu where you can do whatever you need. It really depends on how locked down your machine is. Hopefully not too locked down to complete your assignments.

Comment: Nope! It's close though :P

Comment: Since the computer is restricted by your school, your best bet might be to contact the school's technical support. If there is any. Still, it would be the appropriate first step. Especially if your school is expecting you to learn to program.

Comment: A school should provide an IDE for development. In 2020, it make little sense to write code in notepad or similar tool.

Comment: You have probably tried this but. On windows, next to the start button there's usually a place to search for programs. If so try searching for cmd.exe and running it.

Comment: Maybe win+r to execute a command, cmd / powershell / bash ? Anyway, as Phil1970 mentionned, the admins should allow an IDE and terminal to run.

Comment: @phil of course not notepad.  Use a real editor, like vi.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Pah. [Real programmers use butterflies.](https://xkcd.com/378/)